# Showing a progressDialog while thread is excuted in a fragment

Tags: android, thread-safety, progressdialog

I have a poblem in showing progressDialog (custom ) during thread in OnCreateView of a fragment. I want that the progressDialog is shown during the work of thread (dismiss , if it complete)

```
   // onCreateView 
  @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  frg = inflater.inflate(R.layout.services_frag, container, false);  
  pdialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.drawable.loading_throbber);
  //show pdialog
  pdialog.show();
  Thread initializer=  new Thread(new Task());
  initializer.start();
  retun frg;
    }
```

And the Task runnable:

```
      class Task implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                final int value =i;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                        public void run() {

                    // code works
                     }
                       });
                   handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                            if( value== list.size()-1)
                             {
                                pdialog.dismiss();                        
                              }
                 }
           }
      }
```

**The problem that the progressDialog is shown for a while at the end .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to swap

```
// code works
```

and

```
if( value== list.size()-1)
{
    pdialog.dismiss();                        
}
```

because code in handler.post(...) will be executed in UI thread